# Using browser version types/numbers in Analysis in R

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data

I am doing some analysis using survey data. The target variable is a customer satisfaction metric. It would be helpful to find what versions of what browsers, are causing low customer satisfaction so that survey can be flagged and the problem can be fixed.

However I cam struggling to think of a way to use this variable. There are too many different version numbers to leave the variable as a categorical variable. There are 500 or so different browser versions in the dataset, making me not want to use the variable as a categorical variable. Using the variable as an interval variable would be unwise as well since version 47 in chrome is not comparable to version 10 in IE.

Any ideas on how to use the browser number in the analysis? Below is an example of what the relevant part of the data set looks like.

```
   example<-c("IE", 10, "Desktop")
   example2<-c("Chrome",47,"Desktop")
```

Comment: How many observations do you have?  You could make hierarchical variables (.e.g `example <- c("IE", "IE-10")` and `example2 <- c("Chrome", "Chrome-47")`) and throw them into something like `glmnet` for variable selection.

Comment: @zach there are around 15000 observaitons

Comment: Then having 500 dummy variables is probably fine.  You might want to drop any levels with <5 observations (or maybe 10).

Comment: The easiest approach is to create a recoded variable yourself. (FF, IE, Chrome, Safari, Other) x (Latest versions (past 6 months), Recent versions (2 years - 6 months), Old versions (2+ years)) x (desktop, mobile) = 30 different categories.

Comment: Personally, I'd stick to analyzing only major browser upgrade version numbers.  Minor upgrades are likely to have a very limited impact and be used only by a very small fraction of the population at a time.  For example, I'd consider Firefox 45.0.1 and 45.0.0 one and the same.  You may even choose to concentrate your analysis on the vast majority of browsers in use:  http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp.

Comment: @Jessica Really like your encoding.  I'm going to use that next time I'm analyzing browser data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say exactly what the analysis is to be used for, but, I'd look at something like;

1. Parse the UA string into constituent components using the R ua-parser wrapper. https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-r
2. Group the components by hand (well you get them correctly grouped from the above); browser type & version, make sure you also include operating system and the underling hardware if you can get it (ua-parser will parse it out if it's there)
3. Then as Jessica indicates you might want to hand roll some interaction features based on some semantic rules

HTH